# ¿De qué manera puedo eliminar de una lista todos los números que contenga el dígito ingresado por el usuario?

Tags: c#

Tengo una lista de números del 1 al 100, se le pide al usuario ingresar un dígito entre el 1 y el 9 para eliminar todos los números que empiecen por ese dígito.

```
namespaces ListaEnteros
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         //variable para almacenar el número a borrar
         int borrar;
         //Lista que almacenara los numeros enteros del 1-100
         List<int> Enteros = new List<int>();

         //Ciclo FOR para agregar a la lista los números del 1-100
         for (int i=1; i<=100; i++)
         {
            Enteros.Add(i);
         }
         WriteLine("Generando los N° del 1-100");

         //Ciclo FOR para generar la impresion de la lista de numeros
         for (int num=0; num < Enteros.Count; num++)
         {
            WriteLine($"==>{Enteros[num]}");
         }

         //Pidiendo al Usuario el número a borrar
         WriteLine("Ingrese El Número que desea borrar");

         borrar = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

         if(Enteros.Contains(borrar))
         {
            Enteros.RemoveAll(borrar);
         }

         foreach(var NuevaLista in Enteros)
         {
            WriteLine("Mostrando nueva lista");
         }
         ReadKey();
      } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas implementando mal el método **[RemoveAll](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netframework-4.8)**, ya que esa función te pide por parámetro una condición y tú sólo le estas pasando el numero que escribió el usuario. Además si deseas que elimine todos los números que *empiecen por*... debes convertir los valores a `String` para que de esta forma puedas extraer el primer valor a comparar.

Así que, simplemente cambia el `if`

```
if (Enteros.Contains(borrar))
{
   Enteros.RemoveAll(x => x.ToString().StartsWith(borrar.ToString()));
}
```

Y hará lo que deseas :)